# How to find Google Assistant in Settings=>Apps in order to clear its storage/cache?

Tags: settings, google-assistant

Since [How to stop Google Assistant from freezing Xiaomi Mi Box S 4K's remote control?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/219984/how-to-stop-google-assistant-from-freezing-xiaomi-mi-box-s-4ks-remote-control) received no replies, I'd like to ask a more general question - how to clear Google Assistant's settings?

Or to put it more simply, how do I find Google Assistant in my list of apps in order to reset it there?

It's supposed to be *play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=**com.google.android.apps.googleassistant***, but - in the Settings=>Apps of at least 2 different devices (a phone and a TV - both have Google Assistant in the general settings) - I find neither the aforementioned app ID nor **Assistant** nor **Google Assistant**, not even when system apps are included in my view.

Answer (score 0):

Google assistant is not a separate app it's bundled with the Google App. So to clear the data for the Google Assistant you need to do it with the Google App

Comment: Just the system app called "Google", not any of the countless namesless apps called com.google.something?

Comment: 'com.google.android.apps.googleassistant' is used to launch Assistant. It is not a system app and its tiny in size. The Assistant which we used is bundled in Google App (com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox) so you have to clear data of it in order to clear data of Google Assistant

Comment: FYI, I simply see neither com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox nor com.google.android.apps.googleassistant, not even any com.google.android.apps. I guess the only option according to you is clearing the main Google app itself.

Comment: Yes that's what I was trying to say